# Can I call extension method if I have a PropertyInfo and object with variable for this extension?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, enums, propertyinfo

Can I call extension method, if I have a propertyInfo and object with variable for this extension?

I have an extension:

```
public static string GetTitle(this MyEnum myEnum)
{
    switch (myEnum)
    {
        case MyEnum.One:
            return "one";
        case MyEnum.Two:
            return "two";
        default:
            return "zero";
    }
}
```

and enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  Zero, One, Two
}
```

and the class

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string A {get;set;}
   public MyEnum B {get;set;}
}
```

When I got PropertyInfo of this class, I need to call an extension.
I try to do this

```
// .....
foreach(var prop in properties){
 var value = prop.GetType().IsEnum ? prop.GetTitle() : prop.GetValue(myObj, null).ToString()
 }
// .....
```

But it doesn't work.

I have a several different enums and several different extensions. And I try to get values regardless of the type.

Comment: Please provide details of *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Extension methods do not exist on the type itself, they are "glued" to it in a different way. Either way, extension methods (or any type-specific method) does not exist on `PropertyInfo` objects.

Comment: What type is `prop`?  I'm guessing it's not a `MyEnum`.

Answer (score 2):

My colleges are right that question's code is totally incorrect. prop is a [PropertyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) object, then

```
prop.GetType().IsEnum
```

will always returns false.

First of all You should change this check to

```
prop.GetValue(myObj, null).GetType().IsEnum
```

Then You can call extension method like simple static method:

```
YourClassWithExtensionMethod.GetTitle((MyEnum)prop.GetValue(myObj, null))
```

Full solution will be looks like next code:

```
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(myObj, null).GetType().IsEnum ? YourClassWithExtensionMethod.GetTitle((MyEnum)prop.GetValue(myObj, null)) : prop.GetValue(myObj, null).ToString()
}
```

But you should ensure that your property value actually cast to MyEnum. Then finally we will add new check:

```
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(myObj, null).GetType().IsEnum ? (prop.GetValue(myObj, null) is MyEnum ?  YourClassWithExtensionMethod.GetTitle((MyEnum)prop.GetValue(myObj, null)) : ProcessGenericEnum(prop.GetValue(myObj, null)) ) : prop.GetValue(myObj, null).ToString()
}
```

Now You should hardly optimized this line of code. Retrieve value just once and separate 2 conditions.

```
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    var propertyValue = prop.GetValue(myObj, null);
    if(propertyValue != null)
    {
        var value = propertyValue.GetType().IsEnum
            ? (propertyValue is MyEnum
                ? YourClassWithExtensionMethod.GetTitle((MyEnum) propertyValue)
                : ProcessGenericEnum(propertyValue))
            : propertyValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Good work!

Comment: Except that `prop` is almost definitely not a `MyEnum`.  It's likely a `PropertyInfo` instance.  You'd need `WhatEver.GetTitle((MyEnum)prop.GetValue(myObj, null))` for that to work.

Comment: TY to all for your fixes.

Comment: But, if I don't know what is the type of enum? because I get an object, and I know nothing about its properties.

Comment: Also watch out for null reference after `GetValue(myObj, null)`

Comment: @VadimMartynov Thanks alot for the explanation. Can I change this code for situations, when I don't have information about type of enum? If I get some object with another enum type, need I check type of property for each situation? I get property infos from variable with type Object, and If there is another enum variable in variable I need use another extention like my first.

Comment: @AndrewVA you can implement an extension method for base Enum class: public static string GetTitle(this Enum myEnum). If it's not enough for you then you should add a dictionary that'll be match enum types with processing methods.

Comment: @VadimMartynov The first variant is not for me, because different extentions have different logics. But second solution can help me. thanks.